# Sphinx: specify html path distinct from BUILDDIR/html?

Tags: python-sphinx

In the [sphinx Makefile](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/invocation.html#makefile-options), let's say I specify:

```
BUILDDIR = buildy_mcbuildface
```

So that `make html` creates the documentation webpage under `buildy_mcbuildface/html`. This is a slight annoyance in that the contents  of the `html` folder must be copied to the server location after each build.

Can I specify the html path directly, or is it *always* built under `$BUILDDIR/html`? I have looked at the [html options](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#options-for-html-output), and I see no such path option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with:

Add to the Makefile:

```
HTMLCOPYDIR = /path/to/server/location
```

and also in the Makefile change, add:

```
cp -rT $(BUILDDIR)/html $(HTMLCOPYDIR)
```

after the line:

```
@$(SPHINXBUILD) -M $@ "$(SOURCEDIR)" "$(BUILDDIR)" $(SPHINXOPTS) $(O)
```